# How can I compile the JDK 9 Early Access on my Mac?

Tags: macos, java-9

After downloading the Java 9 early access for Mac, I tried the module quick start guide (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start). However, the code doesn't seem to compile. It fails with the following output:

```
src/com.greetings/module-info.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
module com.greetings { }
^
1 error
```

Anyone get this example to work on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are two JDK 9 early access packages. There is *JDK 9 Early Access* and *JDK 9 Early Access with Project Jigsaw*. I installed the package without Jigsaw because I thought Jigsaw would come automatically with the JDK. Apparently, that isn't the case, at least not for the early access JDK 9. After I installed the right package I was able to compile the QuickStart module code.

The standard JDK 9 comes with an installer, but the JDK w/Jigsaw is just a tar.gz. If you want the Jigsaw JDK version then you'll need to extract the file into the directory */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines*. The result should be a *jdk1.9.0.jdk* folder in this directory, probably along with other JDKs. Hope this helps someone.